# How to get API response key values in PascalCase as same as the object variable name in .net core 3.1 only for one controller or one function?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

This is my Object Class

```
public class MyObject
{
   Public string Var1 { get; set; }
   Public string Var2 { get; set; }
}
```

This is a get function of my controller class

```
[HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetObjList()
    {
      return Ok(new GenericModel<List<MyObject>>
      {
            Data = myobjectList
      });
 }
```

The GenericModel contains

```
public class GenericModel<T>
{
    public T Data { get; set; }
    public string[] Errors { get; set; }
}
```

My expected result look like this

```
{
"Data": [
    {
        "Var1": "val1",
        "Var2": "val2"
    }
        ]
}
```

But I'm getting this,

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "var1": "val1",
        "var2": "val2"
    }
        ]
}
```

I just want to get the output key values as same as the object variables, (in PascalCase)
I tried the solutions to add "AddJsonOptions" into the Startup.cs but they did not work. And I want the response as Pascal case, only for this controller requests, not in all requests including other controllers. (Sounds odd, but I want to try it) Are there any solutions? Is is impossible?

Answer (score 0):

There may be another solution but I suggest building `ContentResult` yourself with [JsonSerializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer.serialize?view=net-6.0#system-text-json-jsonserializer-serialize-1(-0-system-text-json-jsonserializeroptions)):

```cs
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetObjList()
{
    return this.Content(JsonSerializer.Serialize(yourResult, yourJsonOption), "application/json");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Pascal Case serialization use this code in Startup.cs:

```
services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
        {
            options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy= null;
        );
```

Comment: Thank you. This is working. Is there any way to implement this method only for selected controller classes? If I do the above method in Startup.cs, my existing code will break. I just wanted to change my code base step by step without affecting all the code at once.

Comment: Glad to know that, Please accept the answer then. About using in specific controller action, you can use options while serializing like this var person = JsonSerializer.Parse<Person>(json, options);